# How to return a function inside a function

Tags: php

Make a function has_twenty_ones that returns true if at least one of the players in the game has 21, otherwise return false. This function should use the twenty_ones function.

```
function has_twenty_ones($game){
    function twenty_ones($game)
    {
        $players_with_score_21 = [];
        foreach ($game['players'] as $name => $player) {
            $distance = 21 - $player['score'];
            if ($distance < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($distance == 21) {
                $players_with_score_21 = [$name];
            }
        }
        return $players_with_score_21;
    }
    return isset($players_with_score_21);

}
```

what's the best way to code it

Comment: Please show your `$game` array. Something like `print_r($game);`

Comment: Well first, as its a function, you have to call it somewhere in the outer function!!! DUH!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if return of `twenty_ones` function is empty, if it return false overthose return  `twenty_ones` value.

```
function has_twenty_ones($game){
    function twenty_ones($game){
        $players_with_score_21 = [];
        foreach ($game['players'] as $name => $player) {
            $distance = 21 - $player['score'];
            if ($distance < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($distance == 21) {
                $players_with_score_21 = [$name];
            }
        }
        return $players_with_score_21;
    }
    $playersWithScore = twenty_ones($game);
    if (!empty($playersWithScore)) {
       return $playersWithScore;
    } else {
      return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I always post solution first then describe what I did

Comment: But you have moved the function **Out** of the function when the title expressly talks about ___A function In a function___

Comment: There we go, DV removed

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in the OP's code he was not actually calling the inner function from the outer function, so there is little surprise that it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need two functions for this.

As was mentioned by @RiggsFolly, you're not actually making a call to twenty_ones() function. Why not have the following code:

```
function has_twenty_ones($game)
{
    foreach($game['players'] as $name => $player)
    {
        $distance = 21 - $player['score'];
        if ($distance < 0) {
            continue;
        }
        // If at least one player has 21, return true.
        if($distance == 21) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above will return true when it encounters a player who has a score of 21, otherwise it'll return false.

Answer (score -1):

```
function twenty_ones($game)
{
    $players_with_score_21 = [];
    foreach ($game['players'] as $name => $player) {
       $distance = 21 - $player['score'];
       if ($distance < 0) {
        continue;
       }
       if ($distance == 21) {
                    $players_with_score_21 = [$name];
       }
    }
    return $players_with_score_21;
}

function has_twenty_ones($game){
    if (count ($this->twenty_ones($game)) > 0 )
        return true;
    else 
       return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. `$players_with_score_21` isn't defined inside `has_twenty_ones` function `$this` isn't defined too. Btw. it will always return `boolean` value.

Comment: @kcp yes i mean that return isset($this->twenty_ones($game)); i updated my response above

Comment: But you have moved the function **Out** of the function when the title expressly talks about ___A function In a function___

Comment: It's still return `boolean` value because `isset` function can only return `boolean` http://php.net/manual/pl/function.isset.php

Comment: I thought you need that so you can easilly do that return  $this->twenty_ones($game);  it returns your array

Comment: Sorry i didnt read well you question i updated my response have a look above

Comment: You have still removed the inner function from the outer function

Comment: @AfafBENZINOUN now you try to convert array to string (with using `Array.length`). You should use `count()` http://php.net/manual/pl/function.count.php